# Cpanel Server Deployed React App giving error on hitting the website manually with the link

Tags: reactjs, react-router, cpanel, custom-error-pages

I have Deployed my react app in the cPanel server. In the route directory of cPanel i.e. `public_html` I have created another directory called help and placed my website zip files here. If I hit the domain address(http://mywebsite.com/help/) through the button it works fine but if I directly hit the domain(http://mywebsite.com/help/) in google it is showing 404 not found on the server. Images are attached for reference.

If i place my build files in root folder i.e.public_html it is working fine but if i use any sub folder in the root then it is throwing 404 error while refreshing the page.

cPanel 404 Error:

[image: cPanel 404 Error]

cPanel Folder Structure:

[image: cPanel Folder Structure]

Comment: This doesn't seem to be about programming, or programming tools. You will probably find better answers on [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) SE.